# R Markdown two tables side by side HTML - LaTex

Tags: html, html-table, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I have two HTML tables that I would like it to appear side by side when rendered as a PDF.

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc} 
**data**
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

I would like the above table to be on the left and the bottom table on the right. side by side

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc} 
**data**
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

**the current output looks something like this**

[image]

However, I would like it to be side by side. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to wrap it minipages making sure to use a % and leave no spaces to join the two tables.

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] 
  \label{} 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\caption{caption 1}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc} 
** data goes here ** 
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%     
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\caption{caption 2}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc} 
** data goes here **
\end{tabular} 
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

leaving no spaces between the \end{minipage}% and \begin is important.

{minipage}[t]  <- ensures that the two tables both start at the same height